# How to deal with None in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a dataset in the form:

`control_albums_tracks[a][0]['items'][b]['id']`

Where `a` and `b` have items I'd like to iterate over. and `b` contains some `None` values.

No matter what I try, I simply cannot extract the `song['id']` values from my data.

```
control_track_ids = [song['id'] for song in album[0]['items']
                        for album in control_albums_tracks if song['id'] is not None]
```

I've also tried variations of the following trying to accommodate the `None` values:

```
control_track_ids = []

for album in control_albums_tracks:
    for song in album[0]['items']:
        control_track_ids.append(song['id'])
```

Is there any correct way to work with this? I'd like to extract the values into a list (`control_track_ids`).

EDIT: I forgot to include the Traceback. Unfortunately, I've already solved the issue and moved on. The error was: "NoneType object is not subscriptable" when trying to iterate over a list.

Comment: Please show a sample of the data

Comment: The `if song['id'] is not None` may be in the wrong place. Try `[for song in album[0]['items'] if song['id'] is not None for album in control_albums_tracks]`

Comment: The data is too large to post so I had to specify it's structure above

Comment: @MotKohn, thank you for your help, but I've tried that (and tried again now) and I get the same "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Just trying, how about `if song is not None`, because you say that `b` may contain `None`. That means `song` may be `None` therefore you cannot subscript it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
control_track_ids = []

try:
    for album in control_albums_tracks:
        for song in album[0]['items']:
            control_track_ids.append(song['id'])
except TypeError:
    album = None
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your two `for` loop clauses in the wrong order. The outer loop should come first:

```
control_track_ids = [song['id'] for album in control_albums_tracks
                                for song in album[0]['items']
                                if song['id'] is not None]
```

It's also possible that you want `if song is not None` instead of `if song['id'] is not None`, but that part is not as clear (it depends what level the `None`s are showing up at).

Comment: Nothing. I tried adding "if album is not None" and changing song['id'] to just song in the last line. Still get the same error

Comment: You should really include the full traceback of the exception in your question. Without that information, we're all just guessing what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks, I totally forgot. However, I already solved the issue. I added a short version of the error and will mark my issue as solved once StackO allows me to.